# When state changes the right component is not getting displayed in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to display disabled input when the state doesn't include needed value and when it includes remove disabled input and display react tags component:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(professionals);

    if(professionals.length){
        clickSearch();
    }
}, [page, professionals]);
```

```
<div className="column is-6">
    {
       !professionals.includes(item => item.value ==='programmers') ?
           <BaseInput disabled placeholder="usernames"></BaseInput> :
           <ReactTags
               tags={users}
               placeholderText={!users.length?"Search ...":''}
               allowNew={true}
    
               onDelete={(i)=> {
                   const tags = users.slice(0)
                   tags.splice(i, 1)
                   setUsers(tags)
               }}

               onAddition={ (tag) =>{
                   const tags = [].concat(users, tag)
                   setUsers(tags)
               }}
           />
    }      
</div>
```

The fun part is that in `useEffect` I can see the updated professionals in the console but even when it includes the needed value condition is not working and it shows only disabled input. What is wrong and how can be it fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Includes doesn't work for objects. You can use `some` or `filter` functions for that purpose.

Example with `filter`:

```
!!professionals.filter(item => item.value ==='programmers').length
```

Example with `some`:

```
professionals.some(item => item.value ==='programmers')
```

Comment: @TusharShahi  thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @NewTechLover can you put your code in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) so we can check it out?

Answer (score 0):

[.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) does not take a function. You are looking for [.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) ?

```
!professionals.some(item => item.value ==='programmers' ? ...
```